# VB: Populate a textbox with popup from txt

Tags: vb.net, populate

I am creating a vb file, and I have a txt file with some that I want to populate a textbox.
What it is currently doing: It is choosing an option that i input in the textbox that I have created.

What I want it to do: Create a popup with every option from a textbox file, show it on screen, let me choose, and then populate another textbox with my choice.
Current code and screenshot:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseClick
    Dim f As New Form2
    Try
        f.Owner = Me
        '
        ' Before showing the child form populate TextBoxes
        '
        f.TextBox1.Text = "1"
        f.TextBox2.Text = "2"
        f.TextBox3.Text = "3"
        If f.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim Box = (From T In f.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                       Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(T.Text)
                       Select T Order By T.Name).FirstOrDefault

            If Box IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.TextBox1.Text = Box.Text
            End If
        End If
    Finally
        f.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Form 2

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Box = (From T In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
               Where Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(T.Text)
               Select T Order By T.Name).FirstOrDefault

    If Box IsNot Nothing Then
        CType(Me.Owner, Form1).TextBox1.Text = Box.Text
    End If
    CType(Me.Owner, Form1).ActiveControl = CType(Me.Owner, Form1).cmdClose

    Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Image:[image: Populate]

edit: now i only need to make the checkbox into locked textboxes, one line from the text file each.
[image]

Comment: "Create a popup with every option from a textbox file, show it on screen, let me choose, and then populate another textbox with my choice" ...this sounds like a bad workaround for just using a dropdown list?

Comment: Ok. How do i populate a dropdown list from a TXT file? I should be pressing a button "populate" to fill the list every time

Comment: [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms+populate+combobox+from+text+file&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=winforms+populate+combobox+from+text+file&aqs=chrome..69i57.6319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Sorry, it should be another form or popup. Not a combobox.

Comment: why not? That's the most user-friendly solution. What's the advantage of having a popup here? You just want to select from a list of possible options, right? That is the what comboboxes are designed for.

Comment: Client asked it this way. He says no combobox, he prefers a pop up.

Comment: And what will be in this popup? How will you show all the possible options? And how will they choose one? It's not clear what UI you are aiming for exactly. A series of buttons, perhaps? It might be ok-ish, until the list gets large... By the way it's always possible to convince the client there is a better way, if you can shown them it will save them time, or money, or stress - or all 3! In this case, it should save them time when using the system, it will save them money (less code for you to write) and hopefully there is less stress (since they select the option more easily)

Comment: I have managed to progress, actually. I am editing the original post with new image.

Comment: ok so now you have a combobox in the "select server" popup. It's just that it's in a popup, when it could be directly in the form, thus saving  some pointless clicking.

Comment: Client said no popup in the form. Now, i need to tell it "button 1, first line, button 2, 2nd line, button 3 3rd line. Select a button, fill server text with it".

Comment: My advice would be, tell the client you are the technical expert, not them, with experience of building efficient user interfaces according to best practices, and you're going to make their users' life simpler by putting a combobox in the form directly.

Comment: And I don't know what you mean in your last comment by "buttons"...your select server combobox doesn't have any buttons, just list items. When the user selects an item, this triggers an event (SelectedIndexChanged it should be). you can handle that event, and get the selected value.

Comment: It's ok, i got closer. Now i only need to make it read first/2nd/3rd line.